# azure 502 error: When one web api severed by another web api app.

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a web api app up and running on azure,

https://**abc-xyz**.azurewebsites.net/

Now one other web api (https://**test-api**.azurewebsites.net) app also hosted which will talk to above API site. In application settings of this web API, I set below,

`Key` : Master_API_ADD

`Value`: https://**abc-xyz**.azurewebsites.net/

Now, when trying to browse some API controllers,

https://**test-api**.azurewebsites.net/api/users

then I am getting below error,

`502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.`

There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

Comment: How did you achieve this scenario, [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)? Please show us more details to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: i havn't use anything related to URL Rewrite.

Comment: Could you show the code behind `https://test-api.azurewebsites.net/api/users`? Moreover, you could [Remote debugging web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebugwj) by yourself to narrow down this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I did remote debugging and got the issue with my app `https://test-api.azurewebsites.net/api/users`. Now it's fixed